# Possible to estimate the number of users for an Android app?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Are there any statistics that indicate how many users an Android app has based on the number of reviews for it? Are there other ways to tell how many users are using an app?

Comment: You mean beyond the the range of installs displayed with each app?

Comment: @AlEverett: Oh where can I find the range of installs?

Comment: Scroll down a bit on the [app's web page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome). It'll be between "What's New" and "Similar" under the heading "Additional information".

Answer (score 4):

On [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/), you can find the number of installs right at the beginning of the page for the app:

[image: Installs on AppBrain]

On [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps), you will have to scroll a little further down, as with the relaunch the summary has moved to a less ideal position:

[image: Installs on Google Play]

It's just a raw number of installs done via *Google Play*, and does not include other sources (such as *AndroidPIT*, *Pdassi*, or *Amazon*). I don't know how is dealt with users who installed an app and later uninstalled it, but that number should at least give you a raw idea.

Comment: The number you see on Play is total installs rather than current active installs.

Comment: Mark did imply that total installs is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I use many services for tracking the data related to my apps, for example: How many current active users and much more.

For checking the performance of a **specific app**:

If you want to track from your android phone you can use apps like this:
[App Stats for Android (beta)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstats.android&hl=en) ([Phandroid review](http://phandroid.com/2013/05/30/app-stats-for-android-beta/)).

And a very great performance online monitoring tool is **[New Relic](http://newrelic.com/)**. It can help you track down the realtime data just by including their small SDK in your app (if you are a developer).

Comment: Hi, you said "I use many services", which ? Thx